# Slow git clone speed on linux

Tags: github

so basically my internet speed is over 1.5 MB p/s but when I try to git clone a project from git-hub the download speed is less than 50 KB p/s I tried downloading the zip which had almost the same result.
I also tried this:

***git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/project***

but it didn't work

any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to be a Git problem, especially since downloading the zip file from Github.com was also slow.

The Internet is not a truck, it is a [series of tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_of_tubes). Your 1.5 MB tube is simply the last tube in that series. It doesn't matter how fast your tube is if the tubes feeding it are slower. For example, if I hook a firehose up to my kitchen sink I'm still going to only get a kitchen sink's worth of water.

You will have to figure out what in that series of tubes is slowing everything down. It could be that someone on your Internet is doing a big upload or download. It could be a problem with your router or wifi. It could be a problem with your local Internet provider. It could be a bad [network route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table#Function) to Github. If you're using a VPN or proxy it could be that. It could be [an issue at Github](https://www.githubstatus.com/).